# How do I separate items use linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dataset for an articles web site.  Each article has datetime, but I can't separate them according to datetime with Linq.

For Example, this [web site](http://www.counterpunch.org/2013/).

As you can see dataset generates month month and year year.

Using linq how can I separate this dataset?

I thought maybe I can if I use like this `List<List<Article>>` but this defeat.

Say I have a class:

```
 public class Article
 {
      public DateTime PostDate {get;set;}
 }
```

or a Datarow with a `PostDate` column

And a list of these Articles:

```
 List<Article>
```

I'd like to group these articles into first `Year` and then `Month`, based on the `PostDate` using Linq.

So that I can output them as follows:

- 2013                          **| Article.PostDate.Year**

  - December                   **| Article.PostDate.Month**

    - Article Title A        **| Article.Title**
    - Article Title B
  - November
  - October
  - ..
- 2012

  - December
  - November
  - October
  - ...

Comment: What do you mean "separate"?

Comment: Provide an example of the source data you are working with and what you have tried already, along with the expected data structure you want to get out via linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, you're trying to group the articles by year and then by month.

Let's say you have the following Article class:

```
class Article
{
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Article(DateTime postDate, string title)
    {
        PostDate = postDate;
        Title = title;
    }
}
```

And the following sample data:

```
var list = new List<Article>
{
    new Article(new DateTime(2012, 12, 1), "A"),
    new Article(new DateTime(2012, 12, 1), "B"),
    new Article(new DateTime(2012, 11, 2), "C"),
    new Article(new DateTime(2012, 11, 2), "D"),
    new Article(new DateTime(2013, 12, 1), "E")
};
```

You could do the grouping like this:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(a => a.PostDate.Year)
              .Select(a => new { Year = a.Key, Items = a.GroupBy(i => i.PostDate.Month)
                                                        .Select(i => new { Month = i.Key, Titles = i.Select(t => t.Title)})
                                                        .OrderBy(i => i.Month)})
              .OrderBy(a => a.Year);
```

And output it like this:

```
foreach (var year in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Year: " + year.Year);
    foreach (var month in year.Items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Month: " + month.Month);
        foreach (var title in month.Titles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("    Title: " + title);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Year: 2012
  Month: 11
    Title: C
    Title: D
  Month: 12
    Title: A
    Title: B
Year: 2013
  Month: 12
    Title: E
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then you want to be able to group first by year and then by month.

Here is one way:

```
public class Article
{
    public DateTime PostDate {get;set;}
}

void Main()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    //create some fake data!
    List<Article> articles = new List<Article>{
                                        new Article{PostDate=now}, 
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMinutes(1)}, 
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMonths(1)}, 
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMonths(1).AddMinutes(1)}, 
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMonths(2)}, 
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMonths(2).AddMinutes(1)}, 
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMonths(4)},
                                        new Article{PostDate=now.AddMonths(4).AddMinutes(1)}
                                };

    var groupedArticles = from a in articles
                        group a by a.PostDate.Year into articlesByYear
                            select new {
                                Year = articlesByYear.Key,
                                ArticlesByMonth = from a2 in articlesByYear
                                                group a2 by a2.PostDate.Month into articlesByYearByMonth    
                                                select articlesByYearByMonth
                            };


    foreach (var articlesByYear in groupedArticles)
    {
        foreach (var articlesByMonthForCurrentYear in articlesByYear.ArticlesByMonth)
        {
            foreach (var article in articlesByMonthForCurrentYear)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Year: " + articlesByYear.Year +" Month: " + articlesByMonthForCurrentYear.Key + " PostDate: " + article.PostDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Will output:**

```
Year: 2013 Month: 12 PostDate: 12/31/2013 11:40:48 AM
Year: 2013 Month: 12 PostDate: 12/31/2013 11:41:48 AM
Year: 2014 Month: 1 PostDate: 1/31/2014 11:40:48 AM
Year: 2014 Month: 1 PostDate: 1/31/2014 11:41:48 AM
Year: 2014 Month: 2 PostDate: 2/28/2014 11:40:48 AM
Year: 2014 Month: 2 PostDate: 2/28/2014 11:41:48 AM
Year: 2014 Month: 4 PostDate: 4/30/2014 11:40:48 AM
Year: 2014 Month: 4 PostDate: 4/30/2014 11:41:48 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly simpler query which has the same result:

```
        var articles = new List<Article>(new[]
        {
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1)},
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-2)},
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3)},
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1)},
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-1)},
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-2)},
            new Article(){Title="Article A", PostDate=DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-3)},
        });

        var set = from article in articles
                  group article by new { article.PostDate.Year, article.PostDate.Month }
                  into byMonthYear
                  group byMonthYear by byMonthYear.Key.Year
                  into byYear
                  select byYear;
```